# Can I apply a variable to text-based xPath searches on Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

Currently I know you can search for web elements on xpath with this syntax:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='text to be found']"));
```

Is there anyway I can search for elements from a variable String? I would like to be able to make a method like this:

```
public boolean nameExists( String name ) {
     if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()= name ]")) )
        return true;
     else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What have you googled?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
public boolean nameExists(String name) {
     return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + name + "']")).size() != 0;
}
```

---

Remember that [`findElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns a [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) not a `boolean`. Also, if the given element does not exist, Selenium will throw a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html).

Instead, we can utilize [`findElements`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to find all the `WebElement`s with the given `String name` from your XPath. If the returned `List<WebElement>` contains any values (`.size() != 0`), this means at least one `WebElement` with the given `name` exists.